# Custom posttype content metabox

Tags: custom-post-types, metabox, post-content

In a plugin I've created a custom post type that stores xml representing models in the respective posts' content.

I've also created a custom meta box that allows the user to edit the xml with a graphic modeler. The changed xml gets stored in a hidden field's value.

When the user clicks *Save Draft* or *Publish* I want to save this value as the post's content. By using the `save_post` action the content gets saved, however I get redirected to a dead page with `ERR_CONNECTION_RESET` after a very long loading time when clicking on *Save Draft*.

This is my `save_post` action:

```
class MetaBoxes
{
    .
    .
    public function saveModel($postId, $post, $update)
    {
        if (get_post($postId)->post_type != $this->post_type)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (array_key_exists(self::INPUT_ID, $_POST))
        {
            wp_update_post([
                'ID' => $postId,
                'post_content' => urldecode($_POST[self::INPUT_ID])
            ]);
        }
    }
    .
    .
}
```

I *know* there are security issues in the current state. Let's ignore them until the main functionality is fixed.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may be in a recursive loop. if you hooked into `save_post` that will be triggered again when you call wp_update_post.

you can temporarily remove the hook. Not knowing exactly how you have written the hook the below code is a guess.

```
remove_action( 'save_post', [ $this, 'saveModel'] );

wp_update_post([
    'ID' => $postId,
    'post_content' => urldecode($_POST[self::INPUT_ID])
]);

add_action( 'save_post', [ $this, 'saveModel'] );
```

Comment: That does work, thanks! However it doesn't seem like the best solution to me. Shouldn't I rather use another action or a filter?

Comment: @felixlinker This is the recommended method on [WordPress Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post#Avoiding_infinite_loops). I don't know if there is another way to update the post_content without the use of `wp_update_post`

Comment: Okay, thanks! I'll stick to this solution. Makes me kind of sad anyways..